# How do I change the background color of a view controller managed by a UIPageViewController?

Tags: objective-c

I created an onscreen tutorial for my iOS app.

To accomplish this I'm using a UIPageViewController which is managing 3 viewControllers.

```
- (void)setupContentViews{
UIViewController *screenTutorial1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenTutorial_1ViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *screenTutorial2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenTutorial_2ViewController" bundle:nil];
tutorialPages = @[screenTutorial1, screenTutorial2];
```

}

Everything works great, except that when I got to change the background for screenTutorial1 or screenTutorial2 it never gets called. What's the reason for this? Is there a solution?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NSLog(@"line 30)");
}
```

After some experimentation it appears that if I add the code in UIPageViewController (see below) it sets the property. But what if I need to add any custom methods to my View Controllers? Do I need to do everything from UIPageViewController?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that at that point the `view` is nil so you can't change the `backgroundColor`.

You should subclass `UIViewController` and set the `backgroundColor` in `viewDidLoad`. And after that you should initialize the view controllers for the `tutorialPages` ivar like this:

```
YourUIViewControllerSubclass *screenTutorial1 = [[YourUIViewControllerSubclass alloc] initWithNimbName:@"ScreenTutorial_1ViewController" bunble:nil];
```

**Update**

Update your method `setupContentViews` like this:

```
- (void)setupContentViews
{
    ScreenTutorial_1ViewController *screenTutorial1 = [[ScreenTutorial_1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenTutorial_1ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *screenTutorial2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenTutorial_2ViewController" bundle:nil];
    tutorialPages = @[screenTutorial1, screenTutorial2];
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how I have it setup.

Comment: Here's what I have in the .h file

Comment: @interface ScreenTutorial_1ViewController : UIViewController

Comment: If this is the way that you set up then the code from your question and the attachment is wrong. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: You're absolutely right arturgrigor. It worked! Thanks for your time.